# On linux is there any tool can compare 2 flolders and produce a patch file?

Tags: linux, compare, directory

A,B,C file in directory /opt/src

D,E,A file in dircory /opt/dest

compare src and dest, figure out should add B,C to dest and delete D,E, and see if A is changed

and give A a binary patch or just to overwrite it.

all this operation pack in a patch file,including the changed and the missed file content, I can copy this file to another machine to execute.

I know it's simple to write some program to do this, but I don't want invent the wheel again

rsync seems meet most of my needs but don't know how to make a patch.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

old way: diff -uNr /opt/src /opt/dest > /tmp/src.patch

there are programs that automate the process, such as makepatch.

Comment: `gendiff` is one I like to use, since it doesn't require a second copy of the directory.

Comment: another question how about binary files?

Comment: hmm, better post that separately... just got an answer to my own question and I'm busy again!

Answer (score 1):

The program `diff` with the option -r

```
diff [-c| -e| -f| -C n][-br] file1 file2

[...]

-r
  Apply diff recursively to files and directories
  of the same name when file1 and file2 are both
  directories.
```